# Fantasy cycle where a man's spirit is bound to a werewolf-like creature

Tags: story-identification

This a fantasy cycle (3 books?) I read about 15 to 20 years ago.

- The narrator is a wealthy merchant who owns houses in different cities.
- He also has some sort of shamanic power and bound a spirit to watch after is body when travelling in "spirit world".
- However, at one time the link between his body and his spirit is snapped, bounding warden spirit in his body and himself being bound to werewolf-like creature (called Whaz?) among a pack of them.
- Those are not true werewolves bound to moon cycle, rather some bipedal wolves.
- The narrator also like women a lot.

Meanwhile the world is being ruthlessly conquered by a late king's son, called the Beast.

We learn that tyrant is somehow involved in "accidents" happening to king and his wife:

- The king's wife "accidentally" intercepts the flight of a crossbow bolt.
- The king steps on thin ice and drowns.